# MVC 4 (NET 4.5): Creating custom authorization for specific Employee according to Department

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-4.5, role-base-authorization

I'm really new to C#. Currently, I'm doing an intranet system on .NET 4.5 which I need to set up roles and permission. Authentication is based on AD login, so I store their Username (DOMAIN\User) in Employee table. I have a RoleProvider I created but such provider only authorize on generic role the Employee has. What I would like to achieve is, for e.g: any Staff from Department[Technical] cannot view Department[Sales] section. And, within Staff of Technical Dept, only Manager of the Department can manage that particular department. The further I look into authorization, I become lost.

What I have in my database:

[TblDepartment] has many [TblStaffs], and [TblStaffs] is mapped to TblEmployee

[TblRole] has many [TblRoleLevel], and [TblRole:Employee] is mapped to TblEmployee

I'm doing this because, there is another colleague is developing Customer database for Sales Dept use.

It has been a week I'm looking solution for a kind like this.

Comment: Depending on the type of AD login you have (e.g. if you take username and password and check against the AD's LDAP, or if you use the Windowsauthentication module with Negotiate/NTLM to provide single-sign-on with windows credentials) you might be able to query the LDAP or the ClaimsIdentity to get the groupmemberships of the AD account, and you could resolve your application specific roles/rights from those

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Before this, I've checked the AD and I guess the Admin is just lazy put everybody in 'User' group and not setting the business details in the AD which is why I have to do everything using sql database. Else, my task would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MVC 4 Custom attribute and filters available in .Net 4.5. Follow the link below to steps on how to go about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: Try to avoid posting links and instead write the answer directly when it's possible